# Is possible to make an Android APP compatible with 2.3.3 and Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

Im distributing a mobile Android app that i have developed.

The popularity of Android 2.3.3 (API 10, 33% users) convinced me to develop the APK with the Minimum Android API setted to 10.

The problem is this: My app is tablet-friendly, but android tablets requires Min API to 11.

This setting will cut out a lot of phone users.

So what is the solution?
Make another APK for tablets?
Or there is a way to have both?

Thank you all.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: `but android tablets requires Min API to 11`  - complete nonsense.  The only thing MinAPI does is define the lowest version of Android your app will install to.

Comment: @Simon this is [what Google says](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions)

`At a minimum, check the <uses-sdk> element to make sure that:
minSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher.`

Comment: @Univers3: That is a bug in the documentation. I have filed an issue on it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60552

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is.

If you use supported libraries: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

And then create your App out of Fragments - then you can make an App for 2.3.3 with it's own Tablet layout.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html